# Assign instance IP address to Azure VM via browser Portal

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Can I assign an instance IP address to my VM via the browser portal?

If I go to the https://portal.azure.com portal and select the VM, then there's an "IP addresses" option. If I select it then I can choose whether "Instance IP address" is on or off. However, the On option does not actually assign me an IP Address.

I've seem directions for doing it via Azure PowerShell, but I would really so much like to avoid having to install and configure yet another application.

Comment: If you are doing anything in Azure you should really get the Powershell cmdlets.  Setting it up is very easy - run the installer and then call Add-AzureAccount.

Comment: In order to assign static ip to VM you must have powershell environment loaded in your system. This is not possible using azure portal.

Comment: @Atf What are the PowerShell cmdlets to run?

Comment: @Dai : Posting command as answer

Answer (score 0):

Using Azure PS you can get private IP and public IP of VM

```
$VMName = "myvm"
$RGName = "myrg"
$PrivateIP = (Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $VMName -ResourceGroupName $RGName).IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress
$PublicIP = (Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name $VMName -ResourceGroupName $RGName).IpAddress
```

Comment: Ah, those are commands for ARM, not ASM. I found the commands for ASM are `Set-AzurePublicIP` and it requires a name parameter which apparently is meaningless as it's never used for anything.